# Children under parent list item for nav

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, html-lists

I have a drop down menu that I have made but the drop downs don't drop down under their parent item.

My code can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9dwuqwLt/)

I think it might be something to do with this part of the code:

```
nav ul li ul {
position: absolute;
height: auto;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

but I'm not too sure so any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `position:relative` to `nav > ul li`, this ensures that your absolutely positioned sub menus position themselves relative* to the list items they are children of, and not the parent `ul` itself.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/9dwuqwLt/2/)

```
nav > ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-right: 2px solid #e6e7e9;
    margin: -2px;
    position:relative;
}
```

<sup>*It should be noted that the child items positioning themselves relatively to the parent is not related to the parents position being set to `relative`, only the parent having positioning defined.</sup>

Comment: just noticed... this only works in chrome.. firefox and IE still show it under the first nav item...

Answer (score 1):

You need the parent `Li` to be positioned relatively

```
nav > ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-right: 2px solid #e6e7e9;
    margin: -2px;
    position: relative; /* Add this */
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gyfc4yg/)

Comment: just noticed... this only works in chrome.. firefox and IE still show it under the first nav item...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
nav li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

nav li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
}
```